# is it statistically correct to combine paired and unpaired samples together and perform tests?

Tags: statistical-significance, linear-model, predictor, paired-data

I have samples from left hand and right hand of same individuals (11 patients, 22 measurements) and left (4) and right (2) hand from different individuals (6 patients, 6 measurements). Is it possible to combine all together and check for statistical differences between left and right hand?

Comment: This situation is sometimes called (partially) overlapping samples and tests for it are called (partially) overlapping samples tests. e.g. see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Partiallyoverlapping/ . The manual has references. (When the within-pair dependence is strong and the paired observations comprise most of the data, the independent observations might not tend to add a lot of information to what you get with the paired data.) ... also see https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol18-1/p055/p055.pdf ... These should give you further references and suitable search terms.

Comment: thank you so much for your input! just exactly what i was looking for. Is it okay to perform tests without the independent samples?

Comment: thank you so much for your input! just exactly what i was looking for. Is it okay to perform tests without the independent samples?

Comment: 1. It shouldn't lose much efficiency wise if *both* the conditions I mentioned hold; otherwise I wouldn't do it. 2. There is a question - I should have mentioned it before - of why there were some unpaired values. e.g. If those were [*missing not at random*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Types), you have to carefully consider the biases involved in handling the overlapping samples.